# How to convert HDF5 2D arrays to 1D in NumPy?

Tags: arrays, numpy, hdf5

I have a 2d array (480*640) sliced from an HDF5 file, how can I convert it into a 1d array using NumPy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `reshape` function. See http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html for examples.

Comment: More specifically, the OP probably wants `flat_data = x.reshape(-1)` (The documentation mentions it, but many people don't notice that you can substitute an unknown length with `-1`) or `flat_data = x.ravel()`.  There's also `x.flatten()`, but it makes a copy.  `ravel` or `reshape` are the best options, in this case.

Answer (score 0):

ravel() is more specified numpy.array method for array flattening. So if you have, for instance, 2d numpy.array with name A, so A.ravel() will return 1d array containing elements from A.